# Are the limits for getting banned in a casino static?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Winning too much in a casino gets you banned. But is the limit static, as in whenever you have won a specific sum over all time you get banned, or is it a ban for winning too much over a short period of time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The limit is cumulative across multiple trips to the casino. Each casinos limit is independent of the others, and once reached, you will be nicely asked to never gamble there again. The limits:

- **Atomic Wrangler:** 5,000 Chips
- **Vicki & Vance:** 2,500 Chips
- **Gomorrah:** 9,000 Chips
- **The Tops:** 10,000 Chips
- **Ultra-Luxe:** 15,000 Chips

Comment: Thank you. Banning is permanent, right?

Comment: Correct. 8 chars

Comment: So the point where you never can play in a casino again is pretty much impossible to avoid? I've seen slot machines outside of casinos, such as in the NCR's monorail stations. But what about roulette and black jack?

Comment: There are no usable slot machines, roulette wheels or blackjack tables outside of the 5 casinos. Once you've reached the limit, you are forbidden from gambling in that casino for good. It's impossible to avoid if you intend to keep winning. If you feel the need to gamble some more, you could always pick up Caravan...

Comment: to add to this answer, you gain 'perks' 3 times at various # of chips won at each casino before you are banned.  Those perks may include armor, or even a high roller suite in the casino.  If you skip straight to the maximum ban limit, you will miss out on those perks.

Comment: These limits tell when the casino is going to ban you, but you can win more. If you have 9800 chips at The Tops and win 200 at Blackjack, the manager will interrupt your game to ban you. But if you have 9800 chips and win 20000 at the slots, you will be banned, but will be able to cash out all the 29800 chips.

Comment: Also, if you have the Dead Money add-on, there is another casino open to you -- The Sierra Madre. However, you can only "cash out" your chips there for pre-war money. OTOH, you can always sell your pre-war money once you get back to the Mojave. (I'm sitting on something like 13,000 pre-war moneys right now, haven't gotten back to the Mojave yet.)

Comment: @John. Wow, that's quite a bit. At my current barter level, that 6 times 13,000 :D

Comment: @Earlz: Just wait until it's 8 x 13000! (OTOH, by the time I got there, I already had six figures of caps ... )